# I am trying to pop a two dimensional array using Stack in java. How can I get the stack to pop an int[][] data type rather than an object?

Tags: java, stack

This is the code I have:  I am looking to make the getBoard() method return the board that is at the peek of the Stack after popping the most recent board.  Is there anything that I need to change?

```
    public void undo(){
        redo.push(getBoard());
        state.pop();
        board = ((int[][]) state.peek());
    }

public void redo(){
    state.push(getBoard());
    redo.pop();
    board = ((int[][])redo.peek());
}



    public void undoAction(View view){
twentyFortyEight.undo();
        customGrid.updateGrid(twentyFortyEight.getBoard());
        scoreBox.setText((Integer.toString(twentyFortyEight.getScore())));

    }

    public void redoAction(View view){
twentyFortyEight.redo();
        customGrid.updateGrid(twentyFortyEight.getBoard());
    }
```

Comment: I'm so confused about your question. Please show more relevant parts of your code such as `getBoard`, the stack's type and possibly the current implementation of the `Board` object. And please try to clarify what you want a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

to do getBoard() method you need create this method and later do something there or call other methods from already existed

```
int[][] board;
    public int[][] getBoard(){
int[][] b;
//...
return b;
    }

board = getBoard();
```

Comment: I have that method, and it simply returns the current state of the array.  I haven't had problems with getBoard() until trying to call it in the methods that I put on here.

Comment: For example, you use:
customGrid.updateGrid(twentyFortyEight.getBoard());
here we need to understand that we will have parameters int[][], it means you need check it in the method description:
customGrid.updateGrid(int[][] mmm);

Comment: My redo and state variables are stacks of int[][].  So shouldn't I just be able to use the state.peek() method, and it will return an int[][]?